# Embed bokeh plot in markdown

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I could not find any documentation on embedding bokeh plots in markdown styled documents. Is there an easy way to do this using the script and div tags that bokeh.embed.components ?

Comment: no simple solution I guess, I have bokeh plots in ipython notebook (.ipynb or .html). I tried ```ipython nbconvert --to markdown```. but plots are ruined.

Answer (score 2):

If your Markdown flavour supports `<embed>` tags this is possible using the `.html` file generated by [Bokeh's `output_file()`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html?highlight=output%20file#bokeh.io.output_file).

In Python:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

p = figure(title="example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')

output_file("example.html")
show(p)  # Needed to actually save the file
```

In Markdown:

```
<embed type="text/html" src="relative/path/to/example.html" width="600" height="400"></embed>
```

Note that the `width` and `height` attributes are necessary since it won't auto-size.

This method does have the minor drawback of needing to keep the plot files with the Markdown.

Comment: A little lightbulb went on in my head after reading your answer. because i added js/test.js under docs dir then in mkdocs.yml added extra_javascript:  js/test.js which prints to console. And with that embed tag literally anything is possible!

Answer (score 0):

So far the only way I have found is to render the plot as an image and then embedding it into markdown.

Here is one way to do it:

First export the plots as .png files. Therefore you need to install:

```
conda install selenium phantomjs pillow
```

Than you can use:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import export_png

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 3, 4, 5]
p = figure(title="example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
p.circle(x, y, legend="circles", line_width=2)

export_png(p, filename="bokeh_plot.png")
```

In markdown you use the following command to show the image.

```
![bokeh plot](bokeh_plot.png)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.